# Eliminating ADC Noise

Tags: adc, noise

Im currently using STM32F4'S built in 12 bit ADC. When I get my measures, it varies wildly at +- 40 numeric range. Is there a way to eliminate this? I have tried software filtering with no luck.

Also, when I put this mcu in an IP67 EMI filtered box, would it behave smooth? How much of this noise is coming from EMI?

Comment: What is your reference voltage and where do you derive it from?

Comment: @stowoda Excellent point, if the OP is using a SMPS or a DC wall wart to power the micro, and is using the micro's power rail as the Vref, then it'll be all over the place

Comment: The datasheet shows a maximum total unadjusted error of +/- 5lsb (32 counts). The noise you are seeing is (assuming a 3.3V reference) is about 32mV which should show up on a scope if it is on the power or reference rail. Have you read the application note on the ADC? https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group0/3f/4c/a4/82/bd/63/4e/92/CD00211314/files/CD00211314.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00211314.pdf

Comment: Without a circuit and without any firmware source code -- and most importantly, information about your specific application -- this question is impossible to answer. If "software filtering" had no effect, then you weren't doing it right.

Comment: Where's your VDDA coming from? Is there filtering between that and VDD?

Comment: Install a TEN ohm resistor, followed by a 100uF capacitor, in the VDD line. This is 1 millisecond time constant or 160 Hz F3dB, which should knock down any switching-regulator noise by about 60 to 80 dB, IF you can ground the 100UF cap to a magic-clean point.

Comment: @stowoda I'm using USB power at the moment. Is it bad, how to improve?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Do I install them in a low pass filter fashion? Both paralel or res in series cap in parallel? Im using USB power at this moment, If I put them after my boards vref between potentiometers sources, will it work nice?

Comment: @PeterSmith I read it before, It was more of an analysis on how much should you expect internally. At least that was how I get it. Can you elaborate how you derived +/- 5 lsb -- 32 counts analogy, I don't know the LSB in ADC terms. I remember seeing that +5 LSB max calculation noise on sheet, yet I was thinking LSB as 1 bit back then. Clearly I don't understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's often a good idea to put a 0.1uF capacitor between the analog input and analog ground. This can help filter out some of the noise.

[image]

The image above obviously depicts a discrete ADC, but the same concept can be applied to a microcontroller's integrated ADC.

It's impossible to say how much of the noise is internal and how much is external. The best you can do is put it in an EMI-shielded box and see how much it improves. If it doesn't, chances are most of the noise is internal (coming from within the system itself - clocks, thermal noise, etc).

**EDIT:**

As stowoda suggested, the instability could also come from your ADC voltage reference. If you use the microcontroller's power rail as your Vref then your ADC is at the mercy of the noise on the supply line. If it's coming from a battery then you'll mostly just have noise from within the micro. However, if you're powering it with a SMPS or a DC wall wart, or even some linear regulators, then your power rail will be all over the place, and thus your Vref will as well.

Comment: In addition, don't forget that noise can come from input-mux switching as well.  Especially when your signal is sourced from a high-impedance source, like shown in the example above.  This is an issue when your code askes the uC to convert more than 1 adc input channel (ADC1, 2, 3, ...).  Consider longer settling times for each channel as a possible solution.  Or add an good analog buffer before the ADC input.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen how does one add a good analog buffer?

Comment: @DerStrom8 currently I'm using usb power to support my board, in the future, after the print phase I will be switching to external power yet planning to use just USB power as well. Is it a bad source? How can I improve it, would putting say 1uf cap at the main rail improve the stability?

Comment: You really ought to use a dedicated voltage reference, which are a dime a dozen from Mouser.

Comment: @DerStrom8 Don't have mouser in my country sadly, yet I will look up to some. Are you talking about vref chips such as 7805, or wall plugs?

Comment: Mouser, DigiKey, Newark, Avnet, Arrow, any distributor really. And no, Voltage Reference, not Voltage Regulator. A voltage reference provides you with a high-precision voltage with minimal fluctuation over the specified operating parameters.

Comment: @DerStrom8 I was reading this after your comment and It was an A-ha moment for me, do I have to plug a vref into my boards vref pin? Is it the case? I left it floating for all the time I use ADC since now.
 https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/how-to-choose-a-voltage-reference.html

Comment: @DerStrom8 Oh not the distrubitors, can you suggest a device/chip to use in my work? I have other distrubitors in my location, I can find it probably.

Comment: Unfortunately providing recommendations for specific devices is discouraged on this site, because they may quickly become obsolete and no longer useful to future readers. Just do a search for "precision voltage reference". And yes, you would want to connect your voltage reference output to the Vref pin, and configure your micro to use an external reference.

Comment: @DerStrom8 One last question, do potentiometers resistance matters in ADC efficiency? Which one should I go with, 10kohm?

Comment: Do you mean you have a potentiometer serving as the input to your ADC? The one thing I urge you to be aware of is that the input impedance of an ADC is not infinite. The higher your potentiometer value, the more of an effect the input impedance will have and the values may skew from what you expect. For this reason I recommend using a lower-value potentiometer (10k is probably fine). If you MUST use a high value pot, or just want to play it safe, put a voltage follower between the potentiometer output and the ADC input.

Comment: @DerStrom8 Yes, I am using potentiometer as input to my ADC. I don't need higher value or anything specific, I'm just worried about the optimal readings and want to stay on safe side on impedance. Read it somewhere for arduino 10k is the optimal pot resistance, wonder if this is the case for STM32 as well. I've been experimenting with 500-100K range, doesn't seem to change anything. Does using a low resistance like 500 ohm safe as well? Is there a minimum limit too? What do you use for such applications?

Comment: The arduino has an analog input impedance of around 100M, so you probably won't notice much variance at 500-100kohms. If you try throwing a 1M pot or higher on it though, you may start seeing minor differences. This depends on the resolution of the ADC of course (low resolution means bigger "steps" between output counts, and that reduces the chances of seeing small variances). I'm not sure about the STM32, you'll have to check the datasheet. I don't usually connect a pot to an ADC input - usually I have devices with analog outputs connected to the inputs, so I can't make any recommendations.